# What is the best approach of disconnected work after uploading new version of web Site?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

We have in the company a asp.net website which has a pages that depends on a session.

Every week we upload 2-3 times - a new version of the site.

the problem is that the site offers services which depends on Session. and when we upload - the session is gone. (  as it should).

one of the idea was to notify that the site will be down for a while in a special page. but even then - someone could be in a middle of a session and then see a Maintenance page.( a situation that some one has started filling the form  , and in the meanwhile - we downloaded the site with the Maintenance page).

The other idea was to use Sql server session  or  state server.

the Question is : if we save his session(in sql) and shutdown the server - - the user dont see it , and when he is about to press the Save Button - will it work ?

I know theres Un-persistant cookie which saves the session id. so after the server is up again  - and the user still see the page - and he press save - will it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQL Server session you should technically be able to shut down the server, start it back up, and the user hits Save as though nothing happened (once it's back up again) - except for an obvious delay as everything comes back up and loads into memory for the first time.  However, you may have a problem with ViewState errors if you have moved around the controls on the form between posts.

Ideally you have your website mirrored on a server farm with at least two servers, and you do rolling updates.  Don't ask me how to do this tho :-)

Comment: why there should be a problem with the form elements ? if he press "save" - he will send them again... no?

Comment: The View State is validated to prevent users from sending back a different model of the View State to the server.  When this happens you often get a message like `Validation of viewstate MAC failed` or `The state information is invalid for 
this page and might be corrupted.` (see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx).  I'm not saying this will happen, but it can if you try to modify a form live in between post-backs of the same form.  It's better to restart the form pre-populated from the session again.  Just a thought.

Comment: Again, this will only happen if you are making large changes or using complicated controls like GridView, DataGrid, etc. on the page and move things around drastically right between post-back of the same page.  I wouldn't worry too much about it, but just wanted to mention it in case you run into this issue down the road - you know what I'm talking about then :-)

Comment: , i think it will cause error if the other server doesnt have the same machineKey value.